# The Consumer Regulations 2013: limits of applications and 'gambling' (UK law)

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, gambling

The Consumer Contracts (Information, Cancellation and Additional Charges) Regulations 2013 provides consumers and traders with a number of protections and requirements. Regarding limitations of what this law is applicable to, section 6 states:

> Limits of application: general
>
> 6.—(1) These Regulations do not apply to a contract, to the extent that it is— (a)for— (i)gambling within the meaning of the Gambling Act
> 2005(1) (which includes gaming, betting and participating in a
> lottery)

To me it seems that this law contains a number of provisions which may be relevant in dealings between gambling operators and their customers and that aren't in themselves strictly forms of 'gambling'. For example, section 10 (regarding what traders must do to inform customers before entering into a contract) could apply to customers singing up with the operator (?), or section 40 regarding additional charges made to a customer without to prior consent could apply to charging customers for services and charging for their telephone help line, etc.

Does section 6(1)(i) mean in effect that none of this law's provisions are applicable to dealings between gambling operators and customers, or rather that the law is generally applicable in such contexts but is not applicable with regards to how its provisions might apply to gambling in the narrower sense of the act of placing bets, playing casino games, or playing one of their lotteries (for example, the information which must be made available to a customer before placing bets, playing such games, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

### They do not apply at all to gambling

Gambling is instead regulated under the [Gambling Act 2005](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/19/contents).

Comment: Could you confirm the limits/scope of what you mean by ' gambling' please (as that is central to my question)?  The activities carried out by bookmakers which I point out in the question (withdrawals, telephone helpline use, etc.) aren't in themselves forms of gambling, but they are mentioned in that law.

Comment: For clarification, it should be pointed out that in addition to the Gambling Act, in the UK gambling is subject subject to/regulated by various regulations and laws, including The Consumer Protection from Unfair Trading Regulations 2008, The Consumer Rights Act 2015, The UKGC Licence Conditions and Codes of Practice, and the Gambling Commission's statement of principles for licensing and regulations.     https://www.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/licensees-and-businesses/lccp/condition/7-1-1-fair-and-transparent-terms-and-practices

Comment: Notably, some U.K. derivative contracts are regulated as a form of legal gambling rather than as commodities or financial securities.